# iterate on list by pair or triplets

Tags: python, list

I want to iterate on the list of files inside a specific folder, and store files names by pairs words or triplets words.
I created this code:

```
for file_name in os.listdir(path):
    file_name_aslist = file_name.split()
    o = [(file_name_aslist[x], file_name_aslist [x+1]) for x in range(0, len(file_name_aslist ), 2)]
```

it returns this error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The expression work on single list, but dont want to work inside the loop:
for example:

```
list = ['ra', 'ti', 'kaa', 'esss', 'fm', 'am']
print([(list[x], list[x+1]) for x in range(0, len(list), 2)])

[('ra', 'ti'), ('kaa', 'esss'), ('fm', 'am')]
```

also, when I try to iterate on **triplets** , refuse as well

```
print([(list[x], list[x+1], list[x+2]) for x in range(0, len(list), 3)])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Just a pointer, try to give your variables meaningful names. That way, people reading your code both now and in the future will understand your code semantically. :)

Comment: ok, I changed the variables names

Comment: See the `grouper` recipe in the `itertools` documentation.

Comment: you means grouper from  iteration_utilities ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add a if condition when length of the list is not multiple of 2 , append an extra empty string in the list to make it even.
same for triplets. you have to add one or two string.

```
   #donot use split function.

file_name_aslist = os.listdir(path)
if len(file_name_aslist) // 2 == 0 :
   o = [(file_name_aslist[x], file_name_aslist [x+1]) for x in range(0, 
   len(file_name_aslist ), 2)]
else:
   file_name_aslist.append("")

   o = [(file_name_aslist[x], file_name_aslist [x+1]) for x in range(0, len(file_name_aslist ), 2)]
```

Comment: how ? can you please help

Answer (score 1):

you are splitting the names of the files by "  " (space) at this line:

```
file_name_aslist = file_name.split()
```

you can not be sure that all the files have more than 1 word after splitting

what can you do:

```
def chunks_n(my_list, n):
    for e in range(0, len(my_list), n):
        yield my_list[e: e + n]

my_list = ['ra']
print(list(chunks_n(my_list, 2)))
```

**output:**

```
[['ra']]
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing: in your example using a "single list", `list` does not necessarily represent your original `file_name_aslist`. If your file names don't contain spaces, `file_name_aslist` will be a list with a single element, the file name itself. For these cases, it is very easy to verify why `file_name_aslist [x+1]` will throw a `IndexError`.

Do you really expect that `file_name_aslist` be a list with more than one element? Are you not trying to split by other criteria, like `.` (to possibly split by file extension, which is also a bad approach)?